# initialize multiple threads via LIST<Threads>

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(startThread1);
Thread thread2 = new Thread(startThread2);
Thread thread3 = new Thread(startThread3);


thread1.Start();
thread2.Start();
thread3.Start();
 }

void startThread1()
{
    int i = 0;
    int time = 500;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(time);

    LoginUser(username[i], password[i], i);
     i = i + 1;
    time = time + 500;
    Thread.Yield();
}
void startThread2()
{
    int i = 0;
    int time = 500;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(time);

    LoginUser(username[i], password[i], i);
     i = i + 1;
    time = time + 500;
    Thread.Yield();
}


 void startThread3()
{
    int i = 0;
    int time = 500;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(time);

    LoginUser(username[i], password[i], i);
     i = i + 1;
    time = time + 500;
    Thread.Yield();
}
```

My question is how can I initialize a list of threads and inside these threads a function of threads working like standalone thread . because I had to make new function everytime for every thread.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do

Comment: Use [tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) instead

Comment: there is also the [ThreadPool class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.110).aspx). It's also possible to do using [Action delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: i have edited it to make it more clear!

Comment: thanks @Action delegates !will try

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems very strange. You do not need to (and should not) define a method for each thread. The method defines the logic. A thread executes the logic; several threads can all run the same logic, which seems to be the requirement in this case.

I suggest you start by writing a single `async` method that performs the logon:

```
public static async Task LogonUser(string userName, string password)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Logging on user {0} with password {1}", userName, password);
    //Do the actual logon work here
    await Task.Delay(500);  
    Console.WriteLine("Done logging on user {0}", userName);
}
```

Test that method separately and make sure it works the way you want it to.

Once you have it working, you need to figure out how to call it from multiple "threads" of execution at the same time. Usually it is not necessary to create a new thread or use `ThreadStart`; instead, just call it and let it run asynchronously.

To call it for each of your three users, first define an array with user information in it:

```
var userInfo = new []
{
    new { UserName = "User One",   Password = "1111" },
    new { UserName = "User Two",   Password = "2222" },
    new { UserName = "User Three", Password = "3333" }
};
```

And just select the method using LINQ:

```
var tasks = userInfo.Select
    (
        info => LogonUser(info.UserName, info.Password)
    );
await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Output:

```
Logging on user User One with password 1111
Logging on user User Two with password 2222
Logging on user User Three with password 3333
Done logging on user User Three
Done logging on user User One
Done logging on user User Two
```

[Example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aiOwc8)